# Javascript : Zero padding in string

Tags: javascript, string, zero-padding

How to use zero padding in string which is combined with another character? I search for some example but they just show me string in number format.

For Example :

```
"000001" //Only number withount any character
```

I need zero padding for combined character

For example :

```
ABC000001 //This is inital value
```

Then I do a operation to incrase the initial value. So it will be :

```
ABC000002
```

But when I reach "ABC000009". The result must be "ABC000010".

Any answer would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let current = Number('ABC000001'.substring(3));
current++;
let zeroString = 'ABC00000';
zeroString.substring(0, 8 - current.toString().length) + current;
```

- First line gets the current number by removing leading string,
- Second line increments it,
- Third has declaration of wanted string format,
- Forth line is creating a new string in required format.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could

- separate the string in some characters and digits at the right side,
- add a value,
- pad the string and
- return a new string with all parts.

```js
function add(string, value) {
    var [c, d] = string.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/).slice(1);
    
    return c + (+d + value).toString().padStart(d.length, '0');
}

console.log(add('ABC000001', 1));
console.log(add('A0BC00001', 1));
```